# How to display custom posts from a related custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I created two different custom post types: "Videos" and "Locations."
I then created a custom taxonomy called "Video_Categories."
I have assigned this custom taxonomy to both of the custom post types.

What I want to do is display the Videos that have the same terms as one another on the Locations.

For example:

**Video posts:**

- Name: Video 1; Video_Category: Brisbane, Queensland;
- Name: Video 2; Video_Category: Gold Coast, Queensland;
- Name: Video 3; Video_Category: Sunshine Coast, Queensland;

**Location post:**

- Name: Brisbane; Video_Category: Brisbane;

I want to create a query from the Location page that looks at the taxonomy of this post and returns the video posts that have the same taxonomy.

In the above example, the "Video 1" video post would be returned and displayed on the location page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question, this is a little bit different than getting related categories or tags, though still uses a similar premise. There are a few ways you can do this, but one of the easiest may be to use a custom function that utilizes `WP_Query`. Add the following code to your `functions.php` file.

```
// Create a query for the custom taxonomy
function related_posts_by_taxonomy( $post_id, $taxonomy, $args=array() ) {
    $query = new WP_Query();
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy );

    // Make sure we have terms from the current post
    if ( count( $terms ) ) {
        $post_ids = get_objects_in_term( $terms[0]->term_id, $taxonomy );
        $post = get_post( $post_id );
        $post_type = get_post_type( $post );

        // Only search for the custom taxonomy on whichever post_type
        // we AREN'T currently on
        // This refers to the custom post_types you created so
        // make sure they are spelled/capitalized correctly
        if ( strcasecmp($post_type, 'locations') == 0 ) {
            $type = 'videos';
        } else {
            $type = 'locations';
        }

        $args = wp_parse_args( $args, array(
                'post_type' => $type,
                'post__in' => $post_ids,
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'term' => $terms[0]->slug,
            ) );
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    }

    // Return our results in query form
    return $query;
}
```

Obviously you can change anything in this function to get the exact results you are looking for. Have a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query for further reference.

With that in place, you now have access to the `related_posts_by_taxonomy()` function, where you can pass in whichever taxonomy you want to find related posts for. So in your `single.php` or whichever template is being used for your custom post types, you can do something like the following:

```
<h4>Related Posts</h3>
<ul>
<?php $related =  related_posts_by_taxonomy( $post->ID, 'Video_Categories' );
    while ( $related->have_posts() ): $related->the_post(); ?>
        <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi @dpcasady,
I have added this function and called it from the single.php page and it coming back with: 

"Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in".

And it specifies this line as the issue:

"$post_ids = get_objects_in_term( $terms[0]->term_id, $taxonomy );"

Comment: That means you're trying to use a taxonomy that doesn't exist. Are you sure that the custom taxonomy you registered is called `Video_Categories`? Maybe its `Video_Category`?

Comment: You are right I had to remove the uppercase characters in "Video_Category" for it to work correctly. Looks to be working like I wanted. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Hi @dpcasady, nice function. I added the link and the date to the results : `<?php 
$related =  related_posts_by_taxonomy( $post->ID, 'Video_Categories' );
while ( $related->have_posts() ): $related->the_post(); ?>
 <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><span><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></span></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>`